# Is there a way of using JPA repository method keywords for searching for a list of terms in a column?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, repository

I have an `item` table containing a items with a `name` field.

I'm trying to search through these items by a list of given search terms, where each returned item `name` contains ALL of the terms, e.g:

Given search terms

- wheel
- barrow

then the items

- wheelbarrow
- big wheel barrow

will be returned, while

- wheel
- barrow

would not.

I want to use an existing `ItemRepository` to do this, and was wondering if JPA has a way of doing this via method name keywords?

I know I can do this using the `Contains` keyword if I only have a single search term, but that keyword does not support Collection parameters.

Comment: You'll need to write some code that creates a dynamic query and executes it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some logic to build a string with all the values concatenated, e.g:

```
String allValues = items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter, prefix, suffix));
```

and then you can call your ItemRepository with the contains method

Comment: Don't think that's how the `Contains` keyword works in JPA. That would search for the concatenated string as a whole, which would not meet the criteria in the question.

Comment: If what I answered didn't help, maybe you should try a native query. 
Generally Jpa queries works for basic queries, that's insn't you case.